# how to identify what is undefined

Tags: backbone.js

I'm getting an undefined error with a backbone app. I can't figure out what's undefined. IN the index function of the router, I have this

```
  var view = new Enki.Views.EntriesIndex();
  console.log(view);
  $('#container').html(view.render().el);
```

This final line is giving me this error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'el' of undefined

The `console.log(view)` shows that the `view = new Enki.Views.EntriesIndex();` is being instantiated. Part of the log contains

```
   outerHTML: "<div><h1>Enki</h1>↵↵Entries go here↵</div>"
   outerText: "Enki↵↵Entries go here↵"
```

That log output is coming from the render function of the view

```
render: function(){
  $(this.el).html(this.template({
  entries: "Entries go here"
  }));
 }
```

This is the template..

```
  <h1>Enki</h1>

  <%= entries %>
```

...that is not being inserted into  the "container" div but that is being read in the view, as the log output above shows. Nothing is being inserted into the container div on the main page.

```
<div id="container">...</div>
```

Can anyone tell me what is 'undefined' and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reasonable assumption is that your `render` function doesn't return anything, and so `view.render()` is undefined.

Try changing your render function so that it returns a reference back to the `this` object.

```
render: function(){
  $(this.el).html(this.template( {entries: "Entries go here"} ))
  return this // <- important
}
```

Comment: I guess @Michael needs also some words about "undefined". I.e. something like "This is special value that is used to define result that can't be obtained or variable that wasn't set to any specific value. Some languages also use `null`, `Empty`, `None` etc to denote similar meanings."

Comment: ok, thanks, that works, but then if it was just about render not returning anything, why couldn't I just put a return in front of the first line, which I tried but didn't work. ie.. return $(this.el)...

Comment: plus I thought I read that you only need to return this; if you want to chain views, which wasn't the case here.

Comment: @Michael: It is conventional for `render` to `return this`, not mandatory. That allows for the common `$x.append(v.render().el)` idiom that you see in so much Backbone code.

Comment: If you return `$(this.el)` it no longer makes sense to use `view.render().el` - since `render()` is now returning a jQuery selection of a DOM element. Returning `this` returns your backbone view, which has an `el` property.